# Address bar always visible on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am trying to keep the address bar on mobile browser to remain visible while scrolling and not minimised. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If I, as a user, want the address bar to be always visible, I change my browser settings.

Comment: I want to do this because of an out of page interstitial ad. Fixed background image however on mobile when you try to scroll the address bar minimise and causes the image to move as well.

Comment: Interstitial ads and crippling browser functionality? Seems like a good reason *not* to visit that website. But if you really want interstitial ads, why don't you just disable scrolling when it is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for iOS devices, just set your CSS variables to such.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

<html>
    <body>
        <div id='Body'>
            Page content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped i just added this js to stop the bouncing on safari and it works perfect.                                                                                               var xStart, yStart = 0;
document.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
    xStart = e.touches[0].screenX;
    yStart = e.touches[0].screenY;
});
document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
    var xMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenX - xStart);
    var yMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenY - yStart);
    if((yMovement * 3) > xMovement) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});